# Panda print the mark if the name exists

Tags: python, pandas

| Name | Mark |
| --- | --- |
| Ben | 20 |
| James | 50 |
| Jimmy | 70 |

I have a dataframe which looks something like this. I wanna check if the name exists and then it will print the mark for that specific person.

```
if len(df[(df['Name'] == "James")]) != 0:
    print(len(df["Mark"]))
```

Above is my code. Hope to get some advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a Series here with [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) with a `default` argument:

```
marks = df.set_index('Name')['Mark']

marks.get('James', 'missing')
# 50

marks.get('Nonexistent', 'missing')
# missing
```

Or without default, `get` returns None:

```
marks.get('Nonexistent') # no output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the mark of a specified name in your Name column using `loc`. The below will print the Mark of the name you pass, and will return an empty `series` if the name does not exist in your Name column:

```
name_to_retrieve_mark = 'Ben'
df.loc[df.Name.eq(name_to_retrieve_mark),'Mark']

Out[13]: 
0    20
Name: Mark, dtype: int64
```

---

```
name_to_retrieve_mark = 'Sophocles'
df.loc[df.Name.eq(name_to_retrieve_mark),'Mark']

Out[15]: Series([], Name: Mark, dtype: int64)
```